# Chrome and Jquery strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cross-browser

I had to create a simple jsp page that displays 2 tables. There was already a jsp page that generates the table, so all I had to do was to call the page with different parameters and load the result in different divs.

The first thing I tried was to call 2 JQuery loads:

```
$(function() {
    $("#res_05").load("tableGenerator.jsp", 
        {
            "RESOURCE_NAME": "<%= resName1 %>",
        },
        function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            var firstTable = $("#res_05 table table").first();

            $("#res_05").html(firstTable);
            $("<h1> Resource <%= resName1 %> </h1>").insertBefore("#res_05 table");
    });

    $("#res_15").load("tableGenerator.jsp", 
            {
                "RESOURCE_NAME":"<%= resName2 %>",
            },
            function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                var secondTable = $("#res_15 table table").first();

                $("#res_15").html(secondTable);
                $("<h1> Resource <%= resName2 %> </h1>").insertBefore("#res_15 table");
    });
});
```

This simple page works in Firefox and even Internet Eplorer 8, but in Chrome it behaves in a strange manner: it displays only the first table.

After this first try, I centralized the loads in a function before adding more complexity.
So the script become something like this:

```
$(function() {
    loadTable("res_05", "<%= resName1 %>");

    loadTable("res_15", "<%= resName2 %>");
});


function loadTable(divName, resName) {
        $("#" + divName).load("tableGenerator.jsp",
            {
                "RESOURCE_NAME": resName,
            },
            function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                var firstTable = $("#" + divName + " table table").first();

                $("#" + divName).html(firstTable);
                $("<h1> Resource " + resName + "</h1>").insertBefore("#" + divName + " table");
        });
}
```

After this change the page worked on all browsers, even with Chrome.

It seems like this can be caused by a wrong javascript interpretation from Chrome, but using JQuery this should be a rare case.
After all it worked even with IE 8, I didn't expect such a behaviour in Chrome.

I'm not an expert in JQuery, so if it isn't a browser problem i would like to understand what happens in such situations.

Comment: It feels like a race condition to me. I suspect that there's a collision happening with your first iteration that is resolved by your revision. I would attempt to load the second `div` inside an `onSuccess` block. Does your JSP use globals in such a way that is not thread-safe?

Comment: It can be the case, the JSP I'm calling is quite complex, it's a labyrinth of included files and I have little knowledge about how it works. What I don't understand is how if there was a race condition it disappeared after the revision? I tested it on the same data as before, so the loaded tables were of the same size.